# Can't use a polygon to define a board shape in Altium. How to do it?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-fabrication

I have this small single layer LED PCB I created in Altium, with a Polygon poured on the top layer defining the board limits.

[image: PCB]

When I try to create the board shape by using the polygon as reference, Altium says it can't find the complete polygon, and doesn't define the board shape based on it.

If I try to copy the polygon and convert it to its original primitives, all the primitives disappear.

I created the polygon by using arcs and tracks on the top layer.

Is there another way for me to define it as the shape for the PCB?

Comment: Site rule: *Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!* - in other words have you tried Altium forums first before coming here and raised questions on their site? This Q and A site should not be regarded as an Altium support facility.

Comment: @Andyaka I've been searching on and on the whole morning. The only answer I came close is from Altium user manual here: https://www.altium.com/documentation/knowledge-base/altium-designer/convert-a-fill-or-region-into-a-polygon    but It didn't work out for me so far... And I'm still trying...

Comment: @Andyaka If these tool-specific questions are not wanted, the EE-SE rules should be changed, but downvoting each individual question is not a good way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a while as well:

- Duplicate the polygon, e.g. on a mechanical layer
- Select the polygon, set fill style to 'none'.
- Tools -> Convert -> Explode Polygon to Free Primitives (now you have a set of tracks)
- Select all tracks
- Design -> Board Shape -> Define Board Shape from Selected Primitives

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a way to define the board shape directly from a polygon pour, you can easily reproduce your outline on a mechanical layer since it consist only of two different types of arcs. With this outline selected you can use "Design » Board Shape » Define from selected objects" to use it as PCB outline. For more details refer to the [altium documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/defining-board-shape).